# Texts wont align properly to center

Tags: html, css, center

So I got the following code.

HTML

```
            <div id="container">
        <p class="title"> Social Media </p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="deviant">Deviantart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="skype">Skype</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #container {
background-color: #FFF;
background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
height: 250px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-top: 3px solid #C6C6C6;
border-bottom: 3px solid #C6C6C6;
}

p.title {
color: #FFF;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 24px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


#container ul {
text-align: center;
word-spacing: 150px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container ul li {
display: inline;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#container > ul > li > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
letter-spacing: 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 3;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
```

Now, the problem is that the 3 links "TWITTER DEVIANTART SKYPE" wont align exactly as the text above saying "SOCIAL MEDIA" even though it's both aligned to center.

I don't know why though, I want the three links to be centered exactly as the SOCIAL MEDIA text above but it just isn't. Any ideas?

**Here's a JSFiddle showing the issue:**

http://jsfiddle.net/cuLgC/

Comment: In firefox, it is aligning correctly. Is it happening on specific browser?

Comment: @xDrac its working perfectly correct, whats problem?, which browser you checking this source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle with a fix: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuLgC/9/)

The changes are noted below:

```
#container ul {
  /* text-align: center;  moved to li */
  /* word-spacing: 150px; removed, this was causing issue as some words are longer */
  width: 100%;
  display: table;        /* added  */
  table-layout: fixed;   /* added  */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container ul li {
  display: table-cell;   /* added  */
  width: auto;           /* added  */
  text-align: center;    /* moved */
  /* display: inline; removed */
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The misalignment was being caused by: `word-spacing: 150px;` and the fact that the menu options are all different widths. If you used the same word 3 times they would align but different length words are spread according to their width.

Comment: just changing display from `display: inline` to `display: block` would have been a much quicker and better fix, as tables aren't meant for layout, but yeah that works

Comment: @Crouch your suggestion moves the items one under another, which is not what question asks for.

Comment: Apologies @Tanner it's a poorly worded question really, I read it that way at first then changed my mind

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest way but I put `<br>` after two of the list elements and that drops them down.

http://jsfiddle.net/cuLgC/7/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
container ul li{
display: inline
}
```

To

```
container ul li{
display: block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cuLgC/6/

Display inline puts them on one line block puts them on separate lines, hope this helps it works in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

just add `<br>` tag to the list.... here is the fiddle for that..[jsfiddle][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/hh54D/7/   hope this is right...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
#container {
background-color: #FFF;
background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
height: 250px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-top: 3px solid #C6C6C6;
border-bottom: 3px solid #C6C6C6;
}

p.title {
color: #FFF;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 24px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


#container ul {
text-align: center;
word-spacing: 150px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container ul li {
/*display: inline;*/
float: left; 
list-style: none;
width: 33.3%;    
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#container > ul > li > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
letter-spacing: 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 3;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cuLgC/8/)